# Why there exists a selection with empty description in my pivot table?

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table

[image]

As shown in the screenshot above, there exists an empty description selection box (highlighted in yellow) in my pivot table. My variable should only have N/A, Sold perfect, Sold too late and Sold too soon. May I know why it exists and what does it means? Thank you

Comment: Click it and see what is filtered...

Comment: Nothing change to my pivot table

Comment: But actually, it helps me to save my filter even I refresh the data in pivot table, so I found that it is useful and want to create for other pivot table as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter shows all occuring values in your column "Exit at Profit". So probably, there's an empty cell in that column (or a cell containing one or several spaces).

To avoid losing your filter after refreshing data; use the "Filter" option in the Pivot Table menu rather than "Data"->"Filter".

Here's an example of me reproducing your case. The yellow cell just contains a space (" "). That results in one of the filter items to be blank.

[image]

Comment: I think probably is because my title having extra space between "Exit" and "at". Why my filter always reset when I refreshing my data?

Comment: It can't have anything to do with your title, but with one (or several) cells in the column that you are filtering. See the example that I added in my answer above. Also, for me the filter does not reset when I refresh the data. Can you perhaps share a reproducible example?

Comment: Hang on, I think what you are doing is applying a filter to a column in a Pivot table using Data -> Filter. That's not the way to go; Pivot Table has its own Filter functionality under "Filters" . If you set the filter here, it won't reset when you refresh.